# Mapped network drive or Network share - which is better?

Tags: network-share, mappeddrive

We have a Windows 2003 server with about 30 clients.
I am trying to re-organize our network shares when i began wondering:
Why are we even using mapped drives? why not just use network shares e.g. \servername\documents, \servername\photos etc.
I know nothing about the difference so please help.
Thanks

Sholom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasons I would like to have mapped network drives for frequently used shares:

1. Less typing
2. Quick access through "My Computer"
3. CMD.exe does not support UNC paths as current directories.
4. Programs and scripts expecting paths to begin with a drive letter

Comment: Points 1 and 2 would definitely ring true for the end-users I work with.

Answer (score 0):

In the old days, there was a small performance problem with machines running Windows 98/Windows 2000 when not directly mapped to the share.

These days, the mapping is there for nothing more than human interaction, and old school programs needing to have a specific drive mapped for the program to use.

I'd recommend migrating everything over to a UNC drive mappings when you feel the need, because there is only 24 available drive letters, and an unlimited number of UNC drive mappings

Comment: I'd note for completeness and emphasis (like you mentioned) that some applications...programmed by programmers who suck...INSIST on drive letters in order to work.

Comment: Sometimes drive letters are also just plain easier for training purposes, if you don't have too many shares to create.

Comment: Those programmers will be second up against the wall when the revolution comes... First will be the lawyers.